# Downvoting on questions that are on hold

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I don't see why we should continue to allow people to downvote once a question is put on hold.  Perhaps one can argue that we should still be able to upvote, but even that is questionable.  It seems that we should give the OP some time to fix the question before it gets downvoted into oblivion.  Especially for **new users**, I don't think it helps them to see their question get put on hold and for them to continue to get downvoted.  I can't see why this would be a bad feature to implement.  Anyone else have thoughts on the topic?

If you feel the need to tell OP that their question is incredibly horrible, doing so in a constructive manner via a comment seems more useful to me than downvoting once the question is on hold.

Comment: People shouldn't be doing that, unless it's _extremely_ horrible - though we can't stop people from doing so. If we did, then we wouldn't be able to send the message to them that their question was absolutely _crap_.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Regardless, what's the point in allowing it?  It went on hold, so it makes sense to me that voting should be stopped whilst the question is on hold.  If there's something inappropriate, it should be flagged for moderator.  I don't see an advantage to allowing voting to continue.  If you want to send the message that it's "absolutely crap", send it in a message.

Comment: How about users making their questions good ones in the first place?

Comment: @Jeffman the average "not a good fit for SO" question will not see merciless downvoting. The average "do my work for me" or spam questionn will, and those need a clear signal and/or need to go away altogether

Comment: @probablyPekka Perhaps, but what's the point to continue to allow people to downvote before one has the chance to alter the question.  Again, if you want to tell them that the question is horrible, it's probably better to tell them in a comment so they know what's wrong/what to change.  A downvote doesn't help new users nearly as much as a comment...

Comment: @Jeffman you would be surprised to see how many users don't get it, though. Downvotes also have another important function: they contribute towards the low-quality question ban.

Comment: @Jeffman re your edit, that always sucks and I agree it has become very very difficult for a newb to figure out how to ask a viable question on SO. Still - the general argument is that hiding the community's feedback doesn't make sense, and doesn't help you improve, and I tend to agree. You need some resilience and thick skin to prevail, and that's ok IMO

Comment: @Jeffman I bet the downvotes on that kid's question were accompanied by snarky comments as well. Those really suck and may be the bigger part of the problem. I try to accompany my downvotes with nice constructive comments as often as possible - but with seven thousand new questins a day, expecting that to happen on every question simply isnt realistic. (unfortunately)

Comment: @Jeffman: age really should not matter in how we treat users - if that was the case everyone who wanted answers quickly would set their age on their profile to between 13 and 15.

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  The other question was about closed questions that will be deleted.  This is about questions that are on hold.

Comment: @Steve "closed" and "on hold" are the same thing. "on hold" questions will become "closed" ones after a week or so. The new wording is relatively recent.

Comment: @pro five days.

Answer (score 3):

Why not?  Personally, I don't have a problem with this.

Voting should be temporal; that is, a vote reflects the value you get out of the question at the moment that you view it.  If I see a question that is not really suitable for the site, or doesn't offer any help, then I'd downvote it - regardless of its state.

If the question is edited, and I feel that there has been substantial improvement, then I can change my vote on it.

Comment: True, but what are the odds that everyone is going to go back and change their votes?  I can easily conceive of an exceptionally horrible question that after editing could turn into a decent one.

Comment: Slim to nil.  However, that doesn't necessarily mean that one person's downvoting will affect another person's upvoting.  (Despite the fact that *may* already happen, correlation doesn't imply causation.)

Comment: Believe me, I'm all into theory, but in practice, I'm going to say that this is incredibly incorrect, at least with respect to voting on SO.

Comment: The message I get from this post is: do not downvote questions which can be improved. At least this is the approach I use... If the question can be improved, edit it or comment explaining what needs to be done.